# how to make gridpane rows cell to different width in javafx

Tags: javafx

[gridpane different rows width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J96a6.jpg)
i want to make a registration form with Grid Pane of different rows of cell width
like this pictures in javafx i am beginner please help

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly as it vastly improves your chances of getting good answers in return and not have your question downvoted or closed.

Comment: sorry for that i am not a native speaker